# What's the difference between Firebase AngularFireAuth and Auth?

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, import, firebase-authentication

There are two way of importing Authentication.

The first one is

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
```

the second one is

```
import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase introduced a [major overhaul of its JavaScript APIs](https://firebase.blog/posts/2021/07/introducing-the-new-firebase-js-sdk) in mid-2021 to allow unused code from the SDKs to be removed during your build process (a process known as tree-shaking). In these new SDKs they also introduced a `compat` path, that uses the new SDK but the old syntax (and also can't remove the unused code).

The `compat` path in AngularFire uses the [compatibility layer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat) of the v9 JavaScript SDKs.

From the AngularFire [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire#developer-guide):

> AngularFire has a new tree-shakable API, however this is still under active development and documentation is in the works, so we suggest most developers stick with the [Compatibility] API for the time being. See the [v7 upgrade guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/version-7-upgrade.md) for more information.

So for the moment the recommendation is to use the `compat` mode of AngularFire, which means it *does* run with the v9 releases of the JavaSCript SDK, but doesn't gain the benefits of tree-shaing in the AngularFire modules that you use. Functionality-wise the two should be the same though.